# How can I call/invoke another contract(BNA) deployed on same node in HyperLedger Composer. #hyperledger-composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I know I can use `shim.invokeChaincode()` in Hyperledger Fabric.

Our team decided to make a POC on Composer before starting working on Fabric.

While looking for a solution I came across `Calling an External REST Service` but it would be naive to do an external call when the contract is deployed on the same node.

Answer (score 0):

A transaction in Composer (as modeled in your model file) cannot be called from another transaction - however, a transaction processor can call other functions to allow for code modularisation, but it will only be registered as a single transaction request in the transaction registry. That transaction can multiple smart contract updates from one or more transaction functions (if a, update b and c, then update d and add e as a unit of work),  to update/add/delete from different asset or participant registries, as a unit of work. At a Fabric level, transactions proposed have to be “endorsed” by endorsing peers, and only endorsed transactions may be committed to the blockchain (via read/write set) and have an effect on the world state. (The process of endorsement involves an endorsing peer signing the read/write set of a transaction proposal with its certificate).